# Issue on Calling a Function In Another Function In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script like this

```js
function innerfunc(){
    console.log(msg);
}

function showmsg(){
var msg= "This is somthing"
 innerfunc();
}
showmsg();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see I am calling a function `innerfunc()` after declaring the `msg` but I am getting the

> Uncaught ReferenceError: msg is not defined

error! As you can see I never call the method before declaring and assigning the `msg` so why this is happening?!

Comment: msg is  part of the showmsg function scope which is not part of the inner function  or global scope and therefore is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of achieving what you want.

1. **You can try to return values from function.**

```js
function innerfunc(msg){
  alert(msg);
}

function showmsg(){
  var msg= "This is somthing"
  innerfunc(msg);
}
showmsg();
```

2. **Set javascript global variable.**

```js
var msg;
function innerfunc(msg){
  alert(msg);
}

function showmsg(){
  msg = "This is somthing"
  innerfunc(msg);
}
showmsg();
```

Comment: Thanks Rejith R Krishnan but I can not use the global variable since I am getting some data from Ajax call. I mean I am not sure if it is doable there too?

Comment: @Suffii I think if AJAX call is being used, refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success).

Comment: let me explain you a little bit more, I am getting some JSON data through `.done(function(data)`  and I am running some functions based on these `data` now I want to create functions out side of the ajax call and just call them there

Comment: This is exactly what I am working on now and I have problem with `data` which I am getting from Ajax

Answer (score 1):

```
 function innerfunc(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
 }

 function showmsg() {
   var msg = "This is somthing";
   innerfunc(msg);
 }

 showmsg();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that, you should use @Rejith R Krishnan solution, or use global variables.

```
var MSG = "";

function innerfunc(){
    console.log(MSG);
}

function showmsg(){
MSG  = "This is somthing"
 innerfunc();
}
showmsg();
```

Comment: The best practice is to avoid global variables.